# How to play double handed on the piano?

Tags: piano

I normally play the piano with one hand, but want to play it double handed. Is there an easy way to play the piano with two hands?

Comment: I‘ve post my answer  to the linked question of which this here seems to be a duplication ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with anything, it's just something you need to practice.

Playing with both hands does present some unique challenges, though, especially when one hand is doing something different than the other. It'll take some practice to get comfortable playing a rhythm with one hand while the other hand plays a syncopated pattern. Perhaps it's even harder to perform different articulations among the hands. And let's not even get into playing multiple voices within a single hand!

You may want to get a method book, and potentially one designed for adults to learn piano. They space the examples such that there's not a large leap in difficulty between pieces. This way, you can consistently build up your skills at playing both hands with minimal frustration. You'll have much more success if you start with a piece where the left hand plays whole notes the entire time than you will jumping straight into a Bach two-part invention.

You may also be interested in the answers to [Piano scales: Why bother with hands together?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/74699/piano-scales-why-bother-with-hands-together), which addresses some rationale and difficulties for what you're pursuing.